# identity homomorphism $(f\circ g)_{\#} = f_{\#} \circ g_{\#} = (id)_{\#}$ with $f_{\#}$ onto and $g_{\#}$ one to one

Tags: general-topology

suppose $f\circ g = id$ then its $\#$ 
\begin{align}
(f\circ g)_{\#} = f_{\#} \circ g_{\#} = (id)_{\#}
\end{align}
In this case, textbook(any topology related textbook) says $g_{\#}$ is one to one and $f_{\#}$ is onto. 
I want to prove this statement in detail. 
Can you give me some hint or proof of this?

Comment: If $g(x)=g(y)$ then applying $f$ to both sides tells you what? If $x$ is in the codomain of $f$ then $g(x)$ is in the domain of $f$ and $f(g(x))=$?

Comment: I have taken topology and I don't recognize the notation $\#$ and it's use here, what is its definition?

Comment: @JustinBenfield, $\#$ is a map for fundamental group which i defined in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724491/homotpoic-and-of-two-maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have two functions $f: A \rightarrow B, g: B \rightarrow A$ (any functions on any sets, so the argument works for the $f_\#$ etc., 
and we know that $f \circ g = \operatorname{id}_B$.

To see $g$ is 1-1, suppose that $g(b_1) = g(b_2)$ for some points $b_1,b_2 \in B$. 
Then $$b_1 = \operatorname{id}_B(b_1) = (f \circ g)(b_1) = f(g(b_1)) = f(g(b_2)) = (f \circ g)(b_2) = \operatorname{id}_B(b_2) = b_2$$

so $g$ is 1-1.

To see that $f$ is onto: pick $b \in B$. Define $a = g(b) \in A$. Then

$$f(a) = f(g(b)) = (f \circ g)(b) = \operatorname{id}_B(b) = b$$

and so $b$ is in the range of $f$. So $f$ is onto.